# SQLite3 doesn't show anything

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, sqlite, emulation

I am learning from the book: "Learning Android" (Marko Gargenta - O'REILLY) I am in chapter 9 (The Database).

I am trying to show anything useful using sqlite3. I opened the emulator. I opened the File Explorer in eclipse, I found that I have a database in my emulator which has the path

`data/data/saleh.yamba/databases/timeline.db`
`data/data/saleh.yamba/databases/timeline.db-journal`

I followed the book instructions to open the database in sqlite3

```
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50  
Enter ".help" for instructions  
sqlite> adb shell  
   ...> ls /data/data/saleh.yamba/databases/timeline.db  
   ...> cd /data/data/saleh.yamba/databases/  
   ...> sqlite3 timeline.db  
   ...> SELECT * FROM timeline;  
Error: near "adb":syntax error  
sqlite>
```

.....

For example; after `ls /data/data/saleh.yamba/databases/timeline.db` I expected to list something, but what happens is that it just jumps to the next line printing  `...>`

So I can't get anything useful, what is the wrong? How to fix it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adb shell` is not a SQLite command.
I guess what your are trying to do is:

```
$ adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/saleh.yamba/databases/timeline.db
```

to start sqlite3 and open the database

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Is this the right code? I tried it but nothing special. What the next command to show table content.

Comment: Well, ignore the `$` in windows ;-) What does "nothing special" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can't select directly from the db - you would need to select from a table inside the db.
As you most likely don't know the insides of this db try creating one on your own, I guess that shouldn't be much further in your book.

Answer (score 0):

just go with this post.

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html
```

and try to follow same commands.with correct syntax.